# Changing Scenes in ARKit 2

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a scene that is shown when an image is detected. Ideally, I would like to have two scenes loaded when the image is detected but only show one at a time and allow the user to switch through with a button action. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

```
case "qr-code":
                print("trackingWatch")
                activeScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Apple_Watch/apple_watch.scn")!
                activeNode = activeScene?.rootNode.childNodes.first!
                activeNode?.position = SCNVector3Zero
                activeNode?.position.z = -0.15 
                planeNode.addChildNode(activeNode!)
                node.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

The case is the image that loads the active scene. I would like to have one more active scene that can be rotated between the two.

Comment: If you post some code then we can take a look :)

Comment: The question has been updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one scene, what you can do is to attach the scene2's rootNode to the first scene. the idea is to have the whole scenes into 1 node that can be hidden in one tap.

```
let scene2root = scene2.rootnode
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(scene2Root)
```

Then when the button is tapped, hide scene2root. you can even run an action to make a smooth transition.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this question, and the answer I have provided works well, although it is in no way optimised in anyway. It is solely as a basis for your project ^_________^.

Firstly lets create some `variables` and add these under our `Class Declaration`:

```
//1. Variable To Store Our MainContentHolder
var activeNode = SCNNode()

//2. Variable To Determine Whether We Have Created Our Intial Content
var initialModelSet = false

//3. Our Dyanmic Scenes
var modelRootA: SCNNode!
var modelRootB: SCNNode!
```

We will then create a `function` to load the scenes which we would call in `viewDidLoad` e.g:

```
/// Loads Both Overlay Scenes
func setupScenes(){

    guard let activeSceneA = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/OverlayA.scn"),
          let modelRootA = activeSceneA.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Container", recursively: false)  else { return }

    self.modelRootA = modelRootA

    guard let activeSceneB = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/OverlayB.scn"),
          let modelRootB = activeSceneB.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Container", recursively: false)  else { return }

     self.modelRootB = modelRootB

}
```

We will then use our `ARSCNViewDelegate` to handle the initial setup of our model:

```
//---------------------------
// MARK: -  ARSCNViewDelegate
//---------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check We Have Detected An ARImageAnchor & Check It's The One We Want
        guard let validImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
            let targetName = validImageAnchor.referenceImage.name else { return}

        //2. If Our ReferenceImage Is The QRCode & We Havent Set Our Initial Model Then Load It
        if targetName == "QRCode" && !initialModelSet{

            let width = CGFloat(validImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width)
            let height = CGFloat(validImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

            let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)

            activeNode.geometry = planeGeometry
            activeNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
            activeNode.addChildNode(modelRootA)
            node.addChildNode(activeNode)

            //3. Set Our Initial Model Set Variable To True
            initialModelSet = true
        }

    }
}
```

Having done this we need to create an IBAction for our button which will toggle between the desired models e.g:

```
/// Toggles The Scenes Shown On The ActiveNode
@IBAction func toggleScenes(){

    //1. If The 1st Model Is Displayed Then Remove It & Add The 2nd Model
    if activeNode.childNodes.contains(modelRootA){
        modelRootA.removeFromParentNode()
        activeNode.addChildNode(modelRootB)
        return
    }

    //2. If The 2nd Model Is Displayed Then Remove It & Add The 1st Modle
    if activeNode.childNodes.contains(modelRootB){
        modelRootB.removeFromParentNode()
        activeNode.addChildNode(modelRootA)
        return
    }
}
```

Hope it points you in the right direction...